# Which one have better performance for parsing xml ? XQuery or parse xml programmatically?

Tags: c#, xml, performance, xml-parsing, xquery

I want to parse a xml and insert it's data to my db. now which one is better? Sending xml as parameter to sql server and parse it with XQuery or parse it in my c# code?

I want to use recursive cte combine with xquery. is it best solution?

Comment: I think server is faster parse. Use profiler to check performance.

Comment: Your title asks for "better performance", whereas your question asks which is "better" (or "best") without mentioning performance. I get the impression you aren't clear about your objectives. I suspect you can meet your performance requirements using either approach, and that other factors should play a higher role in your evaluation of options: but you have told us so little, I'm only guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a thing always depends on your specific case. For example: if you have a very big XML file and you can reduce the amount of data on the client significantly before sending it over the network, the C# solution may be faster. On the other hand, if your C# solution generates 100 Update-SQL statements from a single XML record, making at least 100 round trips where you otherwise would need just one round trip, the server solution may be faster.

And, also your available hardware (client/server/network speed) makes a reasonable difference between those two solutions.

Best thing when dealing with performance issues is *always*: **measure** it!